# BroadcastReceiver getting null value from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am passing value in broadcastreceiver through intent

in my fragment

```
  final Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    myIntent.putExtra("studentArray", studentNameArray );
    myIntent.putExtra("studentContactArray", studentContactNumberArray );
    myIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    myIntent.putExtra("stime",sheducleTime);

    // Get the alarm manager service
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in my onrecive:

```
studentNameArray = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("studentArray");
            studentContactArray = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("studentContactArray");
            msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            sheduledTime = intent.getStringExtra("stime");
```

I am getting both array value but I am getting null in msg and sheduleTime. I have logged value in fragment they are not null, but received null in broadcastreceiver.
have tried a lot searched a lot stuck in this for a day. what may be the reason whats the wrong here?

Comment: what are the type of msg and scheduledTime?

Comment: In fragment you need getArguments() and in activity its getXExtra()

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solved it .

**1.Use `Bundle`**

`intent.getExtras()` return is `Bundle` .

So you can use `Bundle` in your code .

Try to change like this in your `Fragment` .

```
 myIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
 myIntent.putExtra("stime", sheducleTime);
 // edited here ,add bundle
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putStringArray("studentArray", studentNameArray);
 bundle.putStringArray("studentContactArray", studentContactNumberArray);
 myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**2.Use `getStringArrayExtra`**

Try this in `onrecive`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
studentNameArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("studentArray");
studentContactArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("studentContactArray");
msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
sheduledTime = intent.getStringExtra("stime");
```

Comment: hello, as i said before i am getting array, only problem is not getting string and still it is not working, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: https://copyprogramming.com/howto/android-7-broadcastreceiver-onreceive-intent-getextras-missing-data